# What is wrong with my .htaccess 404 error

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, htaccess

I have created .htaccess under my public_html folder and it is like this:
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

if I type mydomain.com/random it shows the 404 error, however if I add anything else, like mydomain.com/random/texthere it shows up my site without css and not the 404 error page. Why it is doing that ?

Comment: Are you running a Content Management System?  It may have custom 404 handling . . . you could also use developer tools, firebug, etc to verify that you're getting a 404 - sounds like you're more likely getting a 200 . . .

Comment: No I am not running any content management system. I am using raspberry Pi as web server. Apache2 + php + MySQL stack. I have also installed Varnish if it has something to do with that. It is very weird problem...